# NestJS: How to catch internal server error when we try to update violates foreign key constraint?

Tags: nestjs

I have a method that deletes the column by Id. All is working fine, but this table has a relationship with another one, and when I am trying to delete one row, that is connected with relation to another table, I get an error :

```
 update or delete on table "A" violates foreign key constraint "FK" on table "B"
```

And that's fine, but at this moment the Nestjs returns an Internal server error with code 500. Can I catch this moment and send a custom response? For example Bad Request Exception with custom text? Thanks)

Comment: Can you also include the place where you try to invoke this database operation? Have you tried to wrap this call in a try-catch-block and catch these kinds of errors? If this error is caught you can just invoke `throw new BadRequestException('My custom error')`.